# OutOfMemoryException: When reading 11GB XML using simple groovy getting memory error but when reading using plain JAVA not error

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I am reding a large XML of 11GB size using simple groovy script following. 
1. Groovy - Which is giving memmory error.
2. Java - No out of memory error

Both code executed on InteliJ Idea community edition with default VM memory.

Groovy Code

```
def is = new File("TOPOLOGY.xml").newInputStream()
is.eachLine { line ->
   println(line.size())
}
```

JAVA Code

```java
public class ReadXMLJavaLocal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("TOPOLOGY.xml"))) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine().length());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Expecting to uderstand what is wrong with groovy code which is causing memory exception.

Comment: Are you sure that's all your groovy code?  I can't see where that would consume and keep hold of memory... Btw, your groovy example can be written as: `new File("TOPOLOGY.xml").eachLine { println it.length() }`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Groovy code is defining a variable for the file and input stream, whereas your Java is only defining a variable for the scanner object.

The `is` variable in your Groovy code then has to store all of the data of the 11GB file. Java is just printing out one line at a time as it scans through the file.

Comment: So a better comparison would be to use the same Java code in Groovy, with a bit less ceremony, and see how that works. And if you want to get even closer to Java add @CompileStatic.

Comment: after using scanner in groovy, output is similar, my observation is if XML is not pretty printed Scanner is having better results.